# unknown option name-only when I try to pack an archive with git diff and git archive

Tags: git, github

I want to create an archive of files that have changed between commits, while this works on its own:

```
git diff --name-only tag1 tag2
```

and it gives me a list of files that have changed between two named tags, once I combine it with git archive like this:

```
git archive -o update.zip $(git diff --name-only tag1 tag2)
```

I get this error:

```
error: unknown option `name-only'
```

This is the exact command I enter:

```
git archive -o update.zip $(git diff --name-only v1.0.0-beta.1 v.1.0.0-beta.2)
```

I'm on win10 and with git version 2.22.0. I followed this tutorial here: https://tosbourn.com/using-git-to-create-an-archive-of-changed-files/

Comment: Are you typing this in a bash window or in some other command interpreter such as CMD or PowerShell?

Comment: I've done it in PowerShell and also tested it in bash window. In the bash window, I got a different error: fatal: not a valid object name: app/Http/Controllers/Backend/Spa/Settings/MailController.php
so it seems now I can't archive files because I'm on win10 and bash can't convert the path to something compatible that git archive could compress? Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: The *second* error makes sense: you're trying to make a `.zip` archive containing a *deleted* file. That is, diffing `v1.0.0-beta.1` and `v1.0.0-beta.2` probably says: *To convert the first commit to the second, **delete** `app/Http/Controllers/Backend/Spa/Settings/MailController.php`.* So you try to put the deleted file into the archive. Obviously, that's not going to work very well.

Comment: @torek that file exists, this must have to do with / and \ difference in paths on Linux and win10, it says that file does not exist but that file is there.

Answer (score 2):

When you type the command in PowerShell, you see the error

```
error: unknown option `name-only'
```

because PowerShell does not process the word `$(git` in any special way and passes it as well ass `--name-only` unprocessed to `git archive`. There, the command line processor stumbles over `--name-only` is not a valid command line option of `git archive`.

When you type the same command in a bash window, your receive the error

```
fatal: not a valid object name: app/Http/Controllers/Backend/Spa/Settings/MailController.php
```

because you did not follow the cited tutorial sufficiently well. You must specify a revision whose files you want to put in the archive. In particular, your command should be:

```
git archive -o update.zip tag2 $(git diff --name-only tag1 tag2)
```

Notice the additional `tag2` before `$(`.

Comment: That didn't do anything, same error again. Problem with finding a file because "fatal: pathspec 'app/Http/Controllers/Backend/Spa/Settings/MailController.php' did not match any files", yet the file is there.

Comment: the command seems to be working, the one I have executed before except it fails to pack the files that git diff returns, seems it has problem with the path

Comment: "pathspec ... did not match" is quite different from "not a valid object name", isn't it? It does not matter whether the file exists in your working directory. It must exist in the referenced commit (`tag2`). What does `git status` tell you about the file?

Comment: the file is there, I have not deleted any files between these two commits :) Anyways I figured out a better way to do this that will not fail. Output list of files to a single file, then write php script that adds these files to a zip. I can even check if files exist and skip them that way.